# Yahoo openid website compatibility

Tags: php, yahoo-oauth

I am using [Dope-openid](http://stevelove.org/projects/dope-openid/) library in my website but while logging in with a yahoo account users get a message above Click "Agree" to sign into www.mywebsitename.com using your Yahoo! ID.
***Warning: This website does not meet Yahoo!'s requirements for a website address. Do not share any personal information with this website unless you are certain that it is legitimate.***
I don't get this message when I use my yahoo openid with stackoverflow or plaxo. Do you have to partner or like register your site info somewhere at yahoo before using yahoo as an openid provider on your site? Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here... Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this explanation

[OpenID, You and Yahoo!: "Why Yahoo! OpenID doesn't think you're good enough for your users"](http://wilkinsonlab.ca/home/node/31)

Comment: On a sidenote Jitter do you also have some good links for how to implement openid for facebook (not fconnect)...Thanks

Comment: Link is broken, available [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20110623212625/http://wilkinsonlab.ca/home/node/31) at Internet Archive.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://wilkinsonlab.ca/home/node/31) has a nice writeup, and has a link to a sample XRDS document that is unfortunately broken.

But I did find the sample document here (scroll to bottom and translate for your framework):

[Let the rest discover your OpenID relying party](http://blog.facilelogin.com/2008/07/let-rest-discover-your-openid-relying.html)